# Display currency in Text format

Tags: apex, visualforce

How to Display Currency number in Text format

Example: 1000 = One Thousand 
from apex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the gist of the link provided by @thatherahere ( http://salesforcemaniacs.blogspot.co.uk/2016/02/convert-currency-into-words-in-salesforce.html )

The writer (Mohammed Azarudeen) created an Apex class with two methods, one that returns a String representing the bits after the number (e.g. Thousand) and one that returns a String presenting the initial number component (e.g. Ten).

The Apex class:

public with sharing class ConvertCurrencyToWords {

```
    static String[] to_19 = new string[]{ 'zero', 'One',  'Two', 'Three', 'Four',  'Five',  'Six', 'Seven',
                                          'Eight', 'Nine', 'Ten',  'Eleven', 'Twelve', 'Thirteen',  
                                          'Fourteen', 'Fifteen', 'Sixteen', 'Seventeen', 'Eighteen', 'Nineteen' }; 
    static String[] tens = new string[]{ 'Twenty', 'Thirty', 'Forty', 'Fifty', 'Sixty', 'Seventy', 'Eighty', 'Ninety'}; 

    static string[] denom = new string[]{ '', 
                                         'Thousand',   'Million',     'Billion',    'trillion',    'quadrillion',  
                                         'quintillion', 's!xtillion',   'septillion',  'octillion',   'nonillion',  
                                         'decillion',  'undecillion',   'duodecillion', 'tredecillion',  'quattuordecillion',  
                                         's!xdecillion', 'septendecillion', 'octodecillion', 'novemdecillion', 'vigintillion' }; 
// convert a value < 100 to English.   

public static string convert_nn(integer val) { 
         if (val < 20) 
    return to_19[val]; 
  if (val == 100) 
      return 'One Hundred'; 
  for (integer v = 0; v < tens.size(); v++) { 
    String dcap = tens[v]; 
    integer dval = 20 + 10 * v; 
    if (dval + 10 > val) { 
      if (Math.Mod(val,10) != 0) 
        return dcap + ' ' + to_19[Math.Mod(val,10)]; 
      return dcap; 
    }     
  } 
  return 'Should never get here, less than 100 failure'; 
} 
// convert a value < 1000 to english, special cased because it is the level that kicks   
// off the < 100 special case. The rest are more general. This also allows you to  
// get strings in the form of "forty-five hundred" if called directly.  
public static String convert_nnn(integer val) { 
  string word = ''; 
  integer rem = val / 100; 
  integer mod = Math.mod(val,100); 
  if (rem > 0) { 
    word = to_19[rem] + ' Hundred and'; 
    if (mod > 0) { 
      word += ' '; 
    } 
  } 
  if (mod > 0) { 
    word += convert_nn(mod); 
  } 
  return word; 
} 
public static String english_number(long val) { 
  if (val < 100) { 
    return convert_nn(val.intValue()); 
  } 
  if (val < 1000) { 
    return convert_nnn(val.intValue()); 
  } 
  for (integer v = 0; v < denom.size(); v++) { 
    integer didx = v - 1; 
    integer dval = (integer)Math.pow(1000, v); 
    if (dval > val) { 
      integer mod = (integer)Math.pow(1000, didx); 
      integer l = (integer) val / mod; 
      integer r = (integer) val - (l * mod); 
      String ret = convert_nnn(l) + ' ' + denom[didx]; 
      if (r > 0) { 
        ret += ', ' + english_number(r); 
      } 
      return ret; 
    } 
  } 
  return 'Should never get here, bottomed out in english_number'; 
} 
}
```

(sorry for the poor indentation)

Mohammed then creates a trigger based on the Amount value within an Opportunity record.

trigger ConvertCurrencyToWords on Opportunity (before insert, before update) {

```
for (Opportunity c : Trigger.new) {
    if (c.Amount != null && c.Amount >= 0) {

        Long n = c.Amount.longValue();
        string amo = ConvertCurrencyToWords.english_number(n);
        string amo1 = amo.remove(',');
        c.Amount_in_Words__c = amo1;
    } else {
        c.Amount_in_Words__c = null;
    }
}
}
```

I hope this helps :-)